how to read config values angular 18 having config in kubernetes
I am using kubernetes and have a path as "app/config/tokenized" which is mapped to my ("configmap.yaml" -> data)  inside it i have key values.
How to read those key values in angular 18. it's my first time with angular or type scripts
configmap.yaml structure:

I want the values of AppEnvNamePrefix, CacheExpiry, ApiBaseUrl in my angular code

You have to write a script that creates the environment.ts with these properties, that angular will read. Kubernetes or docker will execute this script when its run.

can you please share any tutorial link, I'm a core backend developer and don't know angular

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], making sure to include details like required YAML files in plain text?
